# Volatile HashMap vs ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, caching, concurrency, hashmap

I have a cache class which contains a `volatile HashMap<T>` to store cache items.

I'm curious what would be the consequences of changing `volatile HashMap` to `ConcurrentHashMap`?

Would i gain performance increase? This cache is readonly cache.

What would be the best option to use? just HashMap? Cache is being populated on a interval.

Comment: If it's read-only you need ... neither.

Comment: `volatile` on a `HashMap` means that you cross a memory barrier when you get/set the `HashMap` object.  It does nothing when you add or remove things from the map

Comment: @BrianRoach what would u use?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

First, it appears you don't understand what the `volatile` keyword does. It makes sure that if the *reference value* held by the variable declared `volatile` changes, other threads will see it rather than having a cached copy. It has nothing to do with thread-safety in regard to accessing the `HashMap`

Given that, and the fact that you say the `HashMap` is read-only ... you certainly don't need to use anything that provides thread-safety including a `ConcurrentHashMap`

**Edit to add:** Your last edit you now say "The cache is being populated on a interval"

That's not read-only then, is it?

If you're going to have threads reading from it *while* you are writing (updating the existing HashMap) then you should use a `ConcurrentHashMap`, yes.

If you are populating an entirely new `HashMap` then assigning it to the existing variable, then you use `volatile`

Comment: well that was the reason why i was using volatile, there was a background thread reading from file and making a new hashmap then assigning to the cache. I m planning to change the design, that s why i asked . You answered both cases though. Thanks.

Comment: Well actually you can use `volatile` to make sure people see the most current elements (basically the same way you do to get "volatile" array elements), it's just a) bad performance, b) convoluted, c) doesn't help with the internal race conditions when adding data and d) plain stupid. But doable! ;)

Comment: @Voo what would u use? or how would u do it?

Comment: @Darth Note my comment was about using volatile to add entries on a hashmap and make sure they're visible - not what you want to do.  b2t: I'd simply go with `ConcurrentHashmap` first - it was built for that purpose. If I had a high performance bottleneck in the map, I'd go for Cliff's lockfree HashMap implementation, in any case with a background thread to remove old entries from the cache. Less memory overhead, no big spikes and still quite good performance. If you really only want to create a new cache every X minutes, Michael's solution will work fine.

Comment: @BrianRoach I don't get your comment that a read-only map does not need to be thread-safe.  Some thread _has_ to put some data in the map at some point and if that data is added _after_ the map has been passed around to other threads, you are in trouble.

Comment: I guess you mean an immutable object does not need any synchronization.  You could use `Map immutableMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(someMap)`.

Comment: @toto2 - *Concurrency*. It's perfectly fine if you were to populate a read-only map *before* any other thread were to access it; you do have control of that when programming. Then there is no concurrency therefore no need for synchronization.

Answer (score 6):

You say the cache is read-only, but also being updated on an interval which seems contradictory.

If the whole cache gets updated on an interval, I'd keep using the volatile.
The volatile will make sure that the updated map is safely published.

```
public final class  Cache
{
   private volatile Map<?,?> cache;

   private void mapUpdate() {
      Map<?,?> newCache = new HashMap<>();

      // populate the map

      // update the reference with an immutable collection
      cache = Collections.unmodifiableMap(newCache);
   }
}
```

If the interval update is modifying the same cache, then you probably want to use a ConcurrentHashMap, or copy the map, update the copy, and update the reference.

```
public final class  Cache
{
   private volatile Map<?,?> cache;

   private void mapUpdate() {
      Map<?,?> newCache = new HashMap<>(cache);

      // update the map

      // update the reference with an immutable collection
      cache = Collections.unmodifiableMap(newCache);
   }
}
```

Comment: I would consider to keep cache field non-volatile. Because of Collections.unmodifiableMap final field link to new version of map will be safely published. At some point all threads would pickup up new version of cache map. Usually (but not always!) it doesn't matter if cache will be available not immediately but in couple of milliseconds.

And making this field non-volatile improve CPU cache performance a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar use case for my web application. I am using a HAshMap for my in-memory cache. The use case is as follows -

1. One user request comes in and first checks the cache for existence of a record using an input key. This is done in the add method.
2. If the object is not present then it inserts the new record in the cache.
3. Similarly in the remove method first checks the presence of a record in the cache using the key and if found just removes that.

I want to make sure of two threads are concurrently executing one on add and another on remove method will this approach make sure they at point of them they see the latest data in the cache? If i am not wrong then synchronized method takes care of thread safety where as volatile takes care of visibility.

```
private volatile HashMap<String,String> activeRequests = new HashMap<String,String>();
public synchronized boolean add(String pageKey, String space, String pageName) {
    if (!(activeRequests.get(pageKey) == null)) {
       return false;
    }
    activeRequests.put(pageKey, space + ":" + pageName);
    return true;
}

public synchronized void remove(String pageKey) {       
    if(!(activeRequests.get(pageKey) == null))
        activeRequests.remove(pageKey);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need volatile here if the activeRequests map reference remains same and does not change and only the values inside the map change? Assuming, this is a singleton instance shared by multiple threads. You should use a concurrentHashMap instead of a synchronized method as you don't change anything else here.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, although the [first answer explains correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10357895/469718), depending on use case, using a volatile on a cache that is refreshed and replaced frequently is unnecessary overhead and **can actually be bad or inconsistent** assuming this is just static metadata snapshot and not updated by other threads.

If you take an example of a Http Request that reads everything from the cache to get everything needed, the request uses a reference of the map, then starts reading some keys from the reference, then half way while reading, cache reference is updated to a new hashmap (refresh), now it starts reading a different state of cache and can become inconsistent if entries in cache are not for a specific time snapshot **T**. With volatile, you read Key1:Val1 at T1, Key2:Val2 at **T2** wheras you need Val1, Val2 to be read for the same snapshot at T1. With volatile your reference is always updated, you could read Key1:Val1 first time and Key1:Val2 second time giving different data in the same request.

Without volatile, the request will use a reference always pointing to a reference snapshot until it has completed processing. Without volatile, you will always read Key1:Val1 at T1 and same value Key2:Val1 at **T2**. Once all requests using this reference have completed, the older dereferenced map will be GCed.