# Will reassigning a reference to a map while it is being used by another thread throw an exception?

Tags: java, multithreading, reference

In the code below, the static method `getCustomerIdByClientKey` will be used by multiple threads in a high throughput environment.

The static method `loadCustomers` will called every 10 minutes or so to invalidate the cache and load a new customer set.  Customers may be added or deleted.

The line I'm concerned about, is `clientKeyToCustomerId = newClientKeyToCustomerId;`

If a thread is currently using the `clientKeyToCustomerId` map when it is reassigned, will that thread throw an exception, or will it continue in it's memory space with no problems, or will it kill the whole JVM? :)

I don't want to synchronize the blocks that access the map as I think it would impact performance negatively.

I don't want to call `map.clear()` as, briefly, threads accessing the lookup will get back null results when they shouldn't.

If replacing the map will cause problems, what would be your approach to solving this?

```
package com.mycompany.key;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.mycompany.dao.CustomerDao;
import com.mycompany.model.Customer;

public class CustomerManager {

    private static Map<String, String> clientKeyToCustomerId = 
                   new HashMap<String, String>();

    public static void loadCustomers() {
        List<Customer> allCustomers = new CustomerDao().loadAll();
        Map<String, String> newClientKeyToCustomerId = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (Customer customer : allCustomers) {
            newClientKeyToCustomerId.put(customer.getActiveKey1(),
                    customer.getCustomerId());
            newClientKeyToCustomerId.put(customer.getActiveKey2(),
                    customer.getCustomerId());
        }
        clientKeyToCustomerId = newClientKeyToCustomerId;
    }

    public static String getCustomerIdByClientKey(String pClientKey) {
        return clientKeyToCustomerId.get(pClientKey);
    }

}
```

Comment: It certainly won't kill the thread since either it has the previous value of `clientKeyToCustomerId` or the updated `newClientKeyToCustomerId`.  And only a bad JVM fault causes the JVM to exit.  The problem is whether or not new threads are going to see a completely initialized version of `newClientKeyToCustomerId` since you are not crossing any memory barriers.

Comment: Actually, your other threads may never see the updated map at all, you need to, at the least, make that variable volatile. You really should consider using a concurrent collection.

Comment: Goes to brush up on volatile

Comment: @Perception, I don't think I need a concurrent collection as the map is never written to (after creation), is that correct or am I missing something subtle and important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After being told to read up on volatile, I think the accepted answer in this question solves it [Volatile HashMap vs ConcurrentHashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357823/volatile-hashmap-vs-concurrenthashmap).  I modified the code below.  The volatile keyword stops any threads thread-locally caching the map.

Any thread currently reading from the old map will be out of date, but that is ok from a business perspective.

```
package com.mycompany.key;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.mycompany.dao.CustomerDao;
import com.mycompany.model.Customer;

public class CustomerManager {

    //private static Map<String, String> clientKeyToCustomerId = 
    // new HashMap<String, String>();
    private volatile static Map<String, String> clientKeyToCustomerId = 
               new HashMap<String, String>();

    public static void loadCustomers() {
        List<Customer> allCustomers = new CustomerDao().loadAll();
        Map<String, String> newClientKeyToCustomerId = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (Customer customer : allCustomers) {
            newClientKeyToCustomerId.put(customer.getActiveKey1(),
                    customer.getCustomerId());
            newClientKeyToCustomerId.put(customer.getActiveKey2(),
                    customer.getCustomerId());
        }
        clientKeyToCustomerId = newClientKeyToCustomerId;
    }

    public static String getCustomerIdByClientKey(String pClientKey) {
        return clientKeyToCustomerId.get(pClientKey);
    }

}
```