# volatile mutable object that doesn't change after assignment

Tags: java, thread-safety

Scenario:

```
class Foo {

    volatile Bar bar;
}

class Bar {

    int baz;
}

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    Bar bar = new Bar();
    bar.baz = 1;
    foo.bar = bar;
}
```

Is is guaranteed that baz variable will be always visible, if Bar isn't immutable (baz isn't final or volatile) but baz never changes after bar assignment?

Comment: Where do you exactly run the `for` loop?

Comment: @Renis1235 anywhere, in some thread other than the thread where the value is read

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Digsb question is under the code

Answer (score 1):

The `volatile` is applied only to the variable where you define it.

If you need to be sure that your code works also for nested variables you need to define them `volatile` too.

As an alternative you can encapsulated the code accessing `Bar` variable and nested variables in a `synchronized` block.

The `volatile` keyword grants that the variable is taken from the main memory instead from the registries of the cpu. This grants that:

> … the volatile modifier guarantees that any thread that reads a field
> will see the most recently written value. - Josh Bloch

This happens to the variable declared `volatile`, not to the inner fields. You can use the volatile keyword on the baz variable and in this case you are sure that the code works.

Comment: Thanks, so the answer is NO? Even if I assign bar to volatile foo.bar AFTER bar.baz assignment, is there no guarantee that bar.baz will be visible?

Comment: The problem is not if it is visible or not, but if the value is consistent or not. If two threads works on the value of baz at the same time is possible to have not coherent values. I update the answer to show it

Comment: Yes, I can understant that. But let's say I have 1 thread publishing some global configuration (Bar class) and others threads only read that configuration, my only requirement is that after foo.bar assignment bar.baz has the latest value (I don't have race condition). I assume it's still not safe?

Comment: You need to define baz as volatile

Comment: Thanks you for the answer. I recently came across this question which is very similar to mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357823/volatile-hashmap-vs-concurrenthashmap/10358047

but the accepted answer stated something opposite:

"If you are populating an entirely new HashMap then assigning it to the existing variable, then you use volatile"

Could you please refer to this (HashMap obviously is not thread safe)?

Comment: If I always replace foo.bar with a new Bar instance, there is no way for other threads to read bar.baz from their buffer - meaning the first value read will be the current value (bar.baz is never modified)

Comment: There is another accepted answer that says the opposite: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23855677/java-volatile-reference-to-mutable-object-will-updates-to-the-objects-field

"Assigning newly constructed objects to volatile variables works nicely. Every thread, that reads the volatile variable, will see a fully constructed object. There is no need for further synchronization. This pattern is usually seen in combination with immutable types."